# Getting the date added for a file on an ftp server using java

Tags: java, date, ftp, get

I am making a program which automatically uploads to and downloads from an ftp server.Is there a way to access  the ftp server and find the date and time when a file was added or modified?

Comment: Huh? If you are uploading it, surely you know when you did it?

Comment: If the copy on the ftp server is newer, that version will be downloaded onto the computer and vice versa.

Comment: `rsync` would be better for this, FTP is an old protocol that is best avoided really. Have you tried running "DIR" or "ls" against the FTP servrer to get the dates? Be aware that the FTP server may also be in a different timezone.